# Added custom domain and SSL to bluemix, still receiving error

Tags: ssl, dns, ibm-cloud

The error I am getting is:

This server could not prove that it is "mycustomdomain".com; its security certificate is from *.mybluemix.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

I have created a route in my bluemix dashboard and added the SSL certificate and private key.  Everything looks to be set up.  It looks like when navigating to my site the certificate being used is the one associated with *.mybluemix.net, and not the one I have purchased for my custom domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure DNS for your domain as well.

Basically you need to go to your domain name provider and add a CNAME for your domain that points to the Bluemix region you deployed your application:

- secure.us-south.bluemix.net for US South region
- secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net for United Kingdom region
- secure.au-syd.bluemix.net for Sydney region

After waiting for DNS propagation it should then work.

You can see more details in the following article:

http://www.tonyerwin.com/2014/09/bluemix-ui-ssl-certificates-and-custom.html

Comment: I was using that article to set this up and did not read through thoroughly enough.  The exact issue I was having was that i was using the same CNAME host as in that article (*.bluemix). After you pointed me back to the article, I read more carefully and saw that he was using bluemix as a subdomain.  I replaced the host with www. and everything is working.  Thank you for your help.